# How to make ADAL.js accept an implicit token in URL without writing to localStorage first

Tags: selenium, adal

**Background:** I have a web site which uses ADAL.js to acquire an implicit token identifying the user and allowing communication with the associated web service. Per ADAL guidance, the very first thing it does when the page loads is to call AuthorizationContext.handleWindowCallback(); then if the user isn't logged in, it calls AuthorizationContext.login() to redirect to Azure Active Directory for authentication.

**Issue:** this works great for actual usage, but for my test cases using Selenium, I'd like not to have to go through a separate login on every single test. Since I can use ADAL.NET to acquire a token, it seems like it should be possible for me to just hand that token somehow to ADAL.js in my URL and start off already-logged-in instead of having to do the redirect-redirect login dance. However, ADAL.js doesn't seem to get all of its state from the URL--it looks for certain guids to have been set in localStorage during login(), and if it doesn't find them it won't accept whatever implicit token is in the URL, which means I wind up going through login() anyway regardless of the fact that I've already got a valid token.

**Workaround:** My current plan to is modify the ADAL.js source code to behave differently when localStorage is empty (as it always is when I start a new (Chrome) Selenium instance). But it seems like kind of a hack to modify the source code in order to support the test scenario. Is there a better way that's natively supported by ADAL.js?

I am using AdalJS v1.0.14 but I have no objections to changing versions if necessary.

Comment: Based on my understanding, if you were testing service which require token and don't want to login with Azure AD everytime, you need to provide a facking/mocking function to provide the token instead of using azure-activedirectory-library-for-js.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the guidance.